# Comparing an usart received uint8_t* data with a constant string

Tags: c++, arduino-due, atsam3x

I'm working on an Arduino Due, trying to use DMA functions as I'm working on a project where speed is critical. I found the following function to receive through serial:

```
uint8_t DmaSerial::get(uint8_t* bytes, uint8_t length) { 

// Disable receive PDC
uart->UART_PTCR = UART_PTCR_RXTDIS;

// Wait for PDC disable to take effect
while (uart->UART_PTSR & UART_PTSR_RXTEN);

// Modulus needed if RNCR is zero and RPR counts to end of buffer
rx_tail = (uart->UART_RPR - (uint32_t)rx_buffer) % DMA_SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH;

// Make sure RPR follows (actually only needed if RRP is counted to the end of buffer and RNCR is zero)
uart->UART_RPR = (uint32_t)rx_buffer + rx_tail;

// Update fill counter
rx_count = DMA_SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH - uart->UART_RCR - uart->UART_RNCR;

// No bytes in buffer to retrieve
if (rx_count == 0) { uart->UART_PTCR = UART_PTCR_RXTEN; return 0; } 

uint8_t i = 0;

while (length--) {

    bytes[i++] = rx_buffer[rx_head];

    // If buffer is wrapped, increment RNCR, else just increment the RCR
    if (rx_tail > rx_head) { uart->UART_RNCR++; } else { uart->UART_RCR++; }    

    // Increment head and account for wrap around
    rx_head = (rx_head + 1) % DMA_SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_LENGTH;

    // Decrement counter keeping track of amount data in buffer
    rx_count--;

    // Buffer is empty
    if (rx_count == 0) { break; }
}

// Turn on receiver
uart->UART_PTCR = UART_PTCR_RXTEN;

return i; 
}
```

So, as far as I understand, this function writes to the variable **bytes**, as a pointer, what is received as long as is no longer than **length**. So I'm calling it this way:

```
 dma_serial1.get(data, 8);
```

without assigning its returning value to a variable. I'm thinking the received value is stored to the `uint8_t* data` but I might be wrong.

Finally, what I want to do is to check if the received data is a certain char to take decisions, like this:

```
if (data == "t"){
//do something//}
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing strings like intended by `if (data == "t")`, you'll need a string comparison function like, for example, `strcmp`. For this to work, you must ensure that the arguments are actually (0-terminated) C-strings:

```
uint8_t data[9];
uint8_t size = dma_serial1.get(data, 8);
data[size]='\0';
if (strcmp(data,"t")==0) {
   ...
}
```

In case that the default character type in your environment is `signed char`, to pass `data` directly to string functions, a cast is needed from unsigned to signed:

```
if (strcmp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data),"t")==0) {
   ...
}
```

So a complete MVCE could look as follows:

```
int get(uint8_t *data, int size) {
    data[0] = 't';
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[9];
    uint8_t size = get(data, 8);
    data[size]='\0';
    if (strcmp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data),"t")==0) {
        cout << "found 't'" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
found 't'
```

Comment: The first argument of the `dma_serial1.get()` function needs to be of the `uint8_t*` type. But both like this and as you are showing, it won't compile.

Comment: Hm - `data[9]` will decay to an `uint8_t*` when used as function argument. Did you try out?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying. If I define **data** as `uint8_t data[9]`, when I call `strcmp(data,"t")` it says `invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]` so it won't compile.

Comment: @Dan Berezin: right, the `unsigned` may hinder here. See extended answer.